# pandas - joining multiple lines from one dataframe to just one line in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Datframes, df1 and df2 with each **different dimensions**:

df1=

```
                    timestamp  price  ...  condition (Preis Gesamt)
ISBN                              ...                          
9783411718832  1644767760   1.08  ...          2           4.03
9783411718832  1644767760   4.04  ...          4           4.04
9783411718832  1639948080   4.38  ...          3           4.38
9783411718832  1633536720   5.88  ...          3           5.88
9783411718832  1616377080   2.98  ...          2           5.98
9783411718832  1642252560   4.37  ...          3           7.37
9783411718832  1643644200   4.95  ...          3           7.95
9783411718832  1616377080   5.90  ...          3           8.89
9783411718832  1643644200   4.38  ...          4           4.38
9783411718832  1645194480   4.38  ...          2           4.38
9783411745258  1635163440   4.00  ...          3           4.00
9783411745258  1644321360   1.14  ...          4           4.14
9783411745258  1619435640   1.89  ...          3           4.89
9783411745258  1644321360   5.00  ...          2           9.19
9783411745258  1644321360   5.00  ...          2           9.80
```

15x6

and df2 =

```
              Menge Lagerplatz  ... Preis (VLB) Mwst.
ISBN                            ...                  
9783411718832     1  Lago237-2  ...        9.99   7.0
9783411745258     1  Lago237-2  ...        5.00   7.0
```

2x9

What I'm trying to do is to add a column to df2 called 'offers' which contains the values of df1 where:

`df1['ISBN'] == df2['ISBN']`

(In both Dataframes 'ISBN' works as the index)

***My problem with all of that is, that I have to add multiple rows from df1 to just one row in df2, so I actually have to store df1 as a 'cell' in df2.***

1. I have no idea how to do that, and 2. I feel like there is a better way to solve that problem?

I'd be glad about any help!

Answer (score 0):

As ISBN is your index `df1['ISBN'] == df2['ISBN']` won't work because is an operation involving a column that doesn't exist in your dataframes. You should just merge or join dataframes, and that will be automatically done based on yours indexes.

Check this section of pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html.

Comment: I actually just changed the Index to ISBN, would it be easier to keep the index default and then do a == comparison? When I try to do that i get                                                        ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects  - even though i did reset.index to df1 and df2